# Passing PHP Variable into JavaScript Function

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        FB.api("me/bookvote:download", "post", {

        }, //Missing a , here?
```

however, I am still getting:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 
 for  book: "<?php echo "http://mysite.xom/auction_details.php?name=$item_details["name"]&auction_id=$item_details["auction_id"]";?>",
```

what could be wrong in my php variable to JavacScript?

Comment: Look at the colors in your code, are you sure you got those quotes right ?

Comment: ah sorry, my editor sucks and did not highlight ><

Comment: inspect what is rendered in the browser

Answer (score 3):

Wrap { } around your array items inside your string, like `{$item_details["name"]}`

Answer (score 1):

Magic quotes are no longer supported. Change

`book: "<?php echo "http://mysite.xom/auction_details.php?name=$item_details["name"]&auction_id=$item_details["auction_id"]";?>",`

to

`book: "<?php echo "http://mysite.xom/auction_details.php?name=" . $item_details["name"] . "&auction_id=" . $item_details["auction_id"];?>",`

Answer (score 1):

You're not concatenating properly in your PHP code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        FB.api("me/bookvote:download", "post", {
            book: "<?php echo 'http://mysite.xom/auction_details.php?name='. $item_details['name'] . '&auction_id=' . $item_details['auction_id']; ?>",
            fb:explicitly_shared = "true" //? Is syntactically valid but creates a global
        },
```

*For readability, I replaced double quotes in your PHP code with single quotes.*