# PHP Variable in Echoing JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I have an php script that is echoing JavaScript, in the JavaScript there are PHP variables

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
     FB.init({
    appId: "myid",
    channelUrl: "//mysite/channel.html",
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true // parse XFBML
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        FB.api("me/bookvote:download", "post", {
            book: "<?php echo "http://mysite/auction_details.php?name=$item_details["name"]&auction_id=$item_details["auction_id"]";?>",
            fb:explicitly_shared = "true" //? Is syntactically valid but creates a global
        }, //Missing a , here?
```

However, I am still getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier for book: http://mysite.xom/auction_details.php?name=$item_details["name"]&auction_id=$item_details["auction_id"]";?>",
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is this in a .js file, if so does it get parsed by PHP ?

Comment: You are using a tag `<?php` inside php echo function. It should be like `book: "http://......'.$item_details.'...."`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing PHP Variable into JavaScript Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559481/passing-php-variable-into-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to end your echo quote so it's like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
....
            book: "http://mysite/auction_details.php?name=' . $item_details["name"] . '&auction_id=' . $item_details["auction_id"] . '",
....
```

Answer (score 3):

I can spot multiple issues:

- You try to print variables inside of single quotes. They won't be parsed, you need double quotes, or better yet, HEREDOC, or *even better yet*, don't use echo to print HTML/JavaScript.
- You try to use additional `<?php ?>` tags inside of your echo. That would obviously not work.

Try this. I have removed the echo. Note that the larger PHP tag ends there.

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     FB.init({
    appId: "myid",
    channelUrl: "//mysite/channel.html",
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true // parse XFBML
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        FB.api("me/bookvote:download", "post", {
            book: "<?php echo "http://mysite/auction_details.php?name=$item_details["name"]&auction_id=$item_details["auction_id"]";?>",
            fb:explicitly_shared = "true" //? Is syntactically valid but creates a global
        }, //Missing a , here?
```

Comment: I have no idea if this works, but I'll upvote it just on the "don't use echo to print HTML/JavaScript" line. Seems like a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
book: "http://mysite/auction_details.php?name=' . $item_details["name"] . '&auction_id=' . $item_details["auction_id"] . '",
```

Answer (score 0):

Those variables never got converted to their actual values that are supposed to be used.
Try breaking that string into multiple parts via concatenation.